# xsl check/selected radio buttons using php (data from mysql database)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, forms, xslt

I have an xml document that is transformed using XSL. I have a node that repeats many times that I made into radio buttons. I want to take the results in the database, and have the corresponding radio button values checked/selected. Here is the XSL code:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="root/a/b">
        <input type="radio" name="{autoincrementnumber}" value="{c[1]/@value}"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="c[1]/ctext[@value='1']"/>
    <input type="radio" name="{autoincrementnumber}" value="{c[1]/@value}"/>
<xsl:value-of select="c[2]/ctext[@value='2']"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
```

There are many nodes that are established via this for-each loop, so there are hundreds of radio buttons.  How would I use php to pull from the database, and have it select/check the corresponding radio button?

database is an imploded string in one column:

```
1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,21,....etc
```

XML document
B=1 is selected for each node, so it appears many times.

```
... 

<a>
<b value="1" >
<c value="1">Yes</c>
<c value="2">No</c>
<c value="3">Maybe</c>
</b>
...
```

FINAL RESULT: If  1 is pulled from database , then radio button value 1 is selected. if 2, then radio button 2 is selected.  The checked radio buttons are all based on values in the database imploded as 1.2.1.4.1.2.4.3....etc

Comment: You should post the XML doc as well and clarify which radio button you want selected. `xsl:if` and `xsl:attribute` are probably what you will need.

Comment: Can you post the desired output for the above XML input document?

Comment: `<b="1">` is not well-formed XML.

Comment: Post the desired output? What do you want me to show you? The output should be if 1 then checkbox 1 is checked, if 2 checkbox 2 is checked and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example of attribute usage and nasty XPath expression. Maybe it will help.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{@name}" value="true">
    <x:if test="translate($value, $uppercase, $smallcase)='true' or translate(@checked, $uppercase, $smallcase)='true'">
        <x:attribute name="checked">checked</x:attribute>
    </x:if>
</input>
```

Whole file is at [asyncode.com/xslt/index.xsl](http://asyncode.com/xslt/index.xsl) - use it as a reference.